# Can I link a server that I only have read-access to?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to link a server that I only have read-access to and uses windows authentication to log me in. I'm trying to link it to my local database so I can combine commands in both databases because my web application executes stored procedures.

Is this possible?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sure you can, with the only restriction that you'll be limited to `SELECT` queries on the remote host. All other instructions like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` will fail with remote permission errors.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting denied access when trying to connect it but turns out it had to do with my admin permissions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

From your description, you want to uses windows authentication to log in the linked server.

When a linked server is created by using sp_addlinkedserver, a default self-mapping is added for all local logins. As a result, if the windows account for the local server also exist in the remote account, you can log in the linked server via the current windows account.

Besides after adding the linked server, you can also create a mapping between a login on the local instance of SQL Server and a security account on a remote server. For detailed information, please refer to the [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).